# How to bring the 2d graph in front of the 3d graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab

The 2d graph should be visible when view from 0,90 but when I get the result most of the line does not visible.

```
x=(0:0.5:2);
y=(0:0.5:2);

x=linspace(0,2);
y=linspace(0,2);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
fx=sin(3*(X.^2+Y.^2)).*exp(-0.5*(X.^2+Y.^2));
h1=mesh(x,y,fx);
mxf=max(max(fx));
mif=min(min(fx));
axis([0,2,0,2,mif,mxf]);
surf(x,y,fx)
hold all;
fz= sin (x) .* exp (-x/2);
view(0,90);
plot(x,fz,'r-');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) to place the line above the surface:

```
fz      = sin (x) .* exp (-x/2);
fxAbove = fz*0 + 1.05*max(fx(:));
plot3(x , fz , fxAbove ,'r-');
hold all;
surf(x,y,fx)
view(0,90);
```

I reorganized the plotting order since the surface coloring gets messed up on my system (not sure why).